# Getting index path of the table

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am using group of buttons with different images and tableview with custom cell in my project.every cell having group of components (like imageview,button,label,slider) when pressing each button one cell will be added.
 My button image and also added to imageview of the cell.

How can i get the index of each cell when pressing the button again.

cell will be added when i press the button at first time.
when pressing second time i want to increment the label value inside the cell.so i need the indexpath to cell the cell from the tableview.

Comment: cell.index? this is what you looking for?

Comment: cell will be added when i press the button at first time.

Comment: when pressing second time i want to increment the label value inside the cell.so i need the indexpath to cell the cell from the tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, maybe you can clarify what you're trying to do.

The method indexPathForCell: is a UITableView method that gives you the index of a certain cell.

Clarify your question a bit and maybe we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can call button touch event to get the cell of uitableview -

```
UIView *cellView = (UIVIew *)[button superview];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[cellView superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: You're assuming the button is a direct subview of the cell. However the approach is the same one I took. Either way, using superview to do this sort of stuff is not so nice. I would suggest to OP to have a think about their architecture and maybe consider a redesign.

Comment: @Bergasms Yes, you are correct, Need to understand their architecture. i will work out another option and edit the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your cells, table, or anything like that. this code will work.

```
 -(NSIndexPath *) pathForButton:(UIbutton *) b {
      UITableView *tv = nil;
      UIView *superView = [b superview];
      UIView *cell;
      while(superview != nil && ![superview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]){
           cell = superview;
           superview = [superview superview];
      }

      if(superview != nil && cell != nil){
            tv = (UITableView*)superview;

            return [tv indexPathForCell:cell];
      }
      return nil;
}
```

Comment: button is not inside the cell

Comment: when pressing each button cell will be added along with the button image.